# How to send request to .Net Core controller using jquery

Tags: jquery, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the button on my page:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="BMW" id="sendBMW"/>
```

I try to send **Post** request to controller using **Jquery**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sendBMW").button().click(function () { 
        $.post('/Home/GetCarsByCriteria', 'bmw');
    })
</script>
```

Here my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Car> GetCarsByCriteria(string param) {
   var cars = db.Cars.Where(x=> x.Seria == param).ToList();
   return cars;
}
```

[image]

I tried to add **[FromBody]** attribute in to Controller, but brek-point doesn't work.
Does somebody to know how i can solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the data to the controller as a key/value pair, not a string. The simplest way to do that is to give jQuery an object which it will encode for you. Try this:

```
$("#sendBMW").button().click(function () { 
  $.post('/Home/GetCarsByCriteria', { param: 'bmw' });
})
```

Note that the key of the object, `param` in this case, needs to match the parameter of the Action in your controller.